# How to post data to actionResult method using Ajax.ActionLink?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my view code where an ActionLink method posts data to the controller's ActionResult Method:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.Deal_Date</td>
                <td>@item.Total_Amount_Remaining</td>
                <td>@item.Dealer_Name</td>
                <td>@item.Validity_Date</td>
                <td>@item.Location</td>
                <td>@item.Deal_Amount</td>
                <td>@item.Client_Info.Client_Name</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Recieve payment", "RecievePayment", new { id = item.Deal_ID })</td>

            </tr>
        }
```

In the above code, @Html.ActionLink Method sends 'id' to the 'ReceivePayment' Action Method of the Controller by the Route Values parameter. Following is the code of my controller's Action Method:

```
public ActionResult RecievePayment(decimal id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Sell_Deal sell_deal = db.Sell_Deal.Find(id);
        if (sell_deal == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.Client_ID = new SelectList(db.Client_Info, "Client_ID", "Client_Name", sell_deal.Client_ID);
        return View(sell_deal);
    }
```

I want to achieve the same but with Ajax.ActionLink Method. Following is the code of my Ajax method in the view:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#BtnSearch").click(function () {
        var SearchBy = $("#SearchBy").val();
        var SearchValue = $("#Search").val();
        var SetData = $("#DataSearching");
        SetData.html("");
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "html",
            url: "/SelectDeal/GetSearchingData?SearchBy=" + SearchBy + "&SearchValue=" + SearchValue,
            success: function (result) {
                debugger;
                if (result.length == 0) {
                    SetData.append('<tr style="color:red"><td colspan="3">No Match Data</td></tr>');
                }
                else {
                    $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                        //var clientName = item.

                        var DealDateString = item.Deal_Date;
                        var valDealDate = new Date(parseInt(DealDateString.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, '')));
                        var finalDealDate = valDealDate.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + valDealDate.getDate() + "/" + valDealDate.getFullYear();
                        var ValidityDateString = item.Validity_Date;
                        var valValidityDate = new Date(parseInt(ValidityDateString.replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, '')));
                        var finalValidityDate = valValidityDate.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + valValidityDate.getDate() + "/" + valValidityDate.getFullYear();
                        var val = '<tr>' +
                       '<td>' + finalDealDate + '</td>' +
                       '<td>' + item.Total_Amount_Remaining + '</td>' +
                       '<td>' + item.Dealer_Name + '</td>' +
                       '<td>' + finalValidityDate + '</td>' +
                       '<td>' + item.Location + '</td>' +
                       '<td>' + item.Deal_Amount + '</td>' +
                       '<td> @Ajax.ActionLink("Receive Payment", "RecievePaymentAjax", new { id = item.Deal_ID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }) <td>' +
                       '</tr>';

                        SetData.append(val);
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In the above code, I want to post the 'Id' value to the 'RecievePaymentAjax' Action Method of my controller for further processing, but at Ajax.ActionLink's route value parameter, I am getting the error 'the name item does not exist in the current context'. How can I solve this problem? If there is any other way to achieve this, the please suggest me.

Comment: Hi, Use `data` attribut, like that `$.ajax({..., data:{param1:value1,param2:value2} ,...})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not pass a javascript variable value to the `Ajax.ActionLin`k method call as the route value parameter value, as this method is C# code and it gets executed in the server. The response of your server code execution by the razor view engine will be sent to the browser and javascript execution happens there by the browser's javascript engine.

C# code executes in server, js code executes in browser.

The `Ajax.ActionLink` basically generates the markup for an `a` tag with some html5 data attributes, which the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` script uses to convert the normal link click behavior on this a tag's to it's ajaxified version. Good news is, we can do the same thing.

So simply create an anchor tag, give a css class to it, which we will use to wire up the ajax post behavior

```
"<td><a class='myAjaxlink' 
        href='@Url.Action("RecievePayment","Home")?id=" + item.Id+"'>My link</a></td>" +
```

This code is still using the `Url.Action` helper method to generate the base url (without the parameter) and we are explicitly adding the querystring id to it with our javascript variable. If you check the view source, you will see something like

```
<a href='./Home/RecievePayment?id=101' class='myAjaxlink'>My link</a>
```

Assuming `item.Id` has a value of  `101` for some row in your collection.

Now wire up some click event handler to our a tag with `myAjaxlink` css class to make it ajaxy.

```
$(function () {

    $(document).on("click","a.myAjaxlink", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();  // Stop the normal navigation behavior
            var url = $(this).attr("href");  // Get the href of clicked link
            $.post(url);  // Make an ajax post
    });

});
```

Also it does not make sense to return a view result from an action method which is being called by ajax. You can return a json result or a partial view result. If you want to use the response coming back from the ajax call, add the `done` callback event to your `$.post` method.

```
$.post(url).done(function(r) {
    alert(r);
});
```